# GEOSERVER - DWITHIN not filtering points and returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers, geoserver

first of all, I'm new to Geoserver and Open Layers. And I'm having a problem with a specific layer that is imported on GeoServer

The issue am having is when I try dwithin on one layer it is working and on another layer that's almost the same it is not working?

My CQL filter would look like this

```
cql_filter=dwithin(geom,POINT(345288.4525477942 17571.074456188097),10,meters)
```

An my URL something like this:

```
http://geoserver/ows/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&count=100&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsName=EPSG:31256&format_options=id_policy:true&typeName=my_workspace:LAYER_NAME&request=GetFeature&cql_filter=dwithin%28geom%2CPOINT%28345288.4525477942%2017571.074456188097%29%2C10%2Cmeters%29
```

And If I change LayerName to other name in query it will work fine, but other than that it wont

Also when I try to get Features it is all working fine :/

Does anyone know what could be the problem, or where can I start ?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"?, gives you any error? an empty result?. Both layers that your checking  have the same SRID?.

Comment: Thanks I found issue it was a problem with proj4 a was badly converting lat and longitude